# Cypress filter selected ellements by severar included text

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a select query of several lines something like this:

```
cy.get('#test-container').find('.row')
```

I want to find one, that contains some text (for example 'test title' and 'test value') in different subellements together. Or at least test that this row exist.
Something like this:

```
cy.get('#test-container').find('.row').filter('include.text', 'test title').filter('include.text', 'test value')
```

Comment: Unclear. Can you please post example HTML with comments what exactly you wanna select? One element filtered by different text nodes that are nested within it, or several elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use correct selector.

Ex:

```
cy
  .get('#test-container')
  .find('.row')
  .filter(':contains("test title")')
```

Try this!

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for this for an hour! I didn't see anything like this in the documentation. Can you point me to it?

Comment: Ah. It's that jquery again...  https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Cypress `filter` takes a selector as its parameter, it does not appear to match on text content of the DOM element.

Instead, you could use `cy.contains` with a regular expression.

```
cy.get('#test-container').find('.row').contains(/(?:test title|test value)/)
```

The parentheses and question mark is to indicate a non-capturing group, which matches on any of the items on either side of the pipe. [MDN RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) docs give more info.

Comment: As I know it's return sub element that contain this, not row that contain sub elements with this text.

Comment: Please post the HTML that you are trying to target as @Dwelle requested. But you might try chainging `.children()` after the `find(.row)`